# Could not load file or assembly log4net Version=1.2.10.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, log4net, .net-assembly

when I'm attempting to run my .NET application it's says `"Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' "`.

I'm using CR 2008.

```
Line 51:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 52:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 53:         <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 54:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 55:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after i install CR Run time my problem was solved..i think the matter was between the 32bit and 64bit version.

here is the link http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe

Answer (score 3):

you need to configure it iis 
Open IIS
Go to current server – > Application Pools
Select the application pool your 32-bit application will run under
Click Advanced setting or Application Pool Default
Set Enable 32-bit Applications to True

and thn

Go to %windir%\system32\inetsrv\
Execute the appcmd.exe tool:

Answer (score 0):

Check if log4net is With the crystal reports dlls and make a reference to the dll in you project. If not, use nuget to get it and include it in you application. You can also download in from the log4net website.

Comment: I tried (no luck) the version from log4net website, but that one differs from the version included in CrystalReports. The difference is in Public Key Token.